# Compare two Vector3's

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am not sure If I am comparing these `Vector3`'s correctly.

What I am doing, is this:

```
HashSet<Vector3> handles = new HashSet<Vector3>();
Vector3[] vertices;
HashSet<Vector3> selectedHandles;

void OnEnable(){
    Creator t = (Creator)target;
    Mesh mesh = t.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().sharedMesh;
    if (mesh != null) {
        vertices = mesh.vertices;
        Vector3 lp = t.transform.position;
        foreach(Vector3 v in vertices){
            Vector3 p = (lp - v);
            handles.Add(new Vector3(p.x, -p.z, p.y));
        }
    }
}
```

This method is taking the vertices from a mesh and saving them when the object is selected (note that `new Vector3(p.x, -p.z, p.y)` x and y are reversed due to how the mesh gets imported. This allows me to align the next section of code with the mesh).

I then add the handles within a radius of the mouse, but for simplicity, I will removed it in the following. Now, when I click on the mesh, I am trying to compare my `selectedHandles` to the vertices in the array, but for some reason my code doesn't see them.

```
public void OnSceneGUI(){
    selectedHandles = new HashSet<Vector3>();
    foreach(Vector3 handle in handles){
        Handles.FreeMoveHandle(handle, Quaternion.identity, 0.001f, Vector3.zero, Handles.DotCap);
        selectedHandles.Add(handle);
    }
    CompareSelected();
}

void CompareSelected(){
    if(Event.current.type == EventType.mouseDown){
        foreach(Vector3 handle in selectedHandles){
            for(int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++){
                if(Vector3.Distance(vertices[i], handle) < 0.01f){
                    Debug.Log("Hi");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am comparing incorrectly?

Comment: That looks okay at first glance. If you step through with a debugger, is it getting to the point of comparing distances in `CompareSelected`? I'd want to make sure those loops and data structures are correct.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to convert it back to its original value, here is how I did that:

**CompareSelected()**

```
Creator t = (Creator)target;
Vector3 lp = t.transform.position;
foreach(Vector3 handle in selectedHandles){
    for(int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++){
        Vector3 p = (handle - lp);
        Vector3 h = new Vector3(p.x, -p.z, p.y);
        float dist = Vector3.Distance(vertices[i], h);
        if(dist < 0.01f){
            newV[i] = h + (-t.transform.forward * 0.01f);
        }
    }
}
```